# inheriting an interface and setting access-modifiers

Tags: inheritance, interface, access-modifiers

Would like to do "private set;". Is there any alternative?

```
public interface IFoo
{
    IEnumerable data { get;  set; }

}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public IEnumerable data
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

}
```

Comment: By making it private you're breaking the contract of the interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the set accessor from the interface:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    IEnumerable data { get; }

}
```

Or you can implement the interface as explicit, but then you will need to somehow implement the set method:

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{

    public IEnumerable data
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    IEnumerable IFoo.data
    {
        get { return data; }
        set { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    }
}
```